# How to handle Null Pointer Exception of AnchorPane object in javafx

Tags: javafx

I am building a javafx application using `afterburner`. I have main window with a AnchorPane. In this AnchorPane i have MenuBar and an another AnchorPane with `fx:id=contentPane`. In this `contentPane` i am trying to load another scene which have a different Presenter which gives me an NPE while it is fine if i am doing so with a menuAction. See the code below and more details..

This is my Main class which start the stage.

```
public class App extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        MainView mainView = new MainView();
        Scene scene = new Scene(mainView.getView()); 
        stage.setTitle("Main");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception { 
        Injector.forgetAll();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Here is main presenter

```
public class MainPresenter implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    AnchorPane contentBox;

    private ObjectProperty<FormOpener> newFormProperty ;

    ReturnsInputView returnsView ;
    ReturnsInputPresenter returnsPresenter;
    InwardsInputView inputView;
    InwardsInputPresenter inwardsPresenter;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        this.newFormProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty();
        this.newFormProperty.addListener(new ChangeListener<FormOpener>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends FormOpener> observable, FormOpener oldValue, FormOpener newValue) {
                if(newValue!=null){
                    InwardsInputView inputView = new InwardsInputView();
                    inwardsPresenter = (InwardsInputPresenter) inputView.getPresenter();
                    contentBox.getChildren().add(inputView.getView());
                } 
            }
        }); 
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        this.returnsView = new ReturnsInputView();
        this.returnsPresenter = (ReturnsInputPresenter) returnsView.getPresenter(); 
        this.contentBox.getChildren().add(returnsView.getView());
    }

    public void showIncomingForm(){
        this.returnsView = new ReturnsInputView();
        this.returnsPresenter = (ReturnsInputPresenter) returnsView.getPresenter(); 
        contentBox.getChildren().add(returnsView.getView());
    }

    public ObjectProperty<FormOpener> newFormProperty(){
        return newFormProperty;
    }

}
```

Here is main.fxml

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" minHeight="180.0" prefHeight="362.0" prefWidth="503.0" styleClass="airpad" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.qaf.MainPresenter">
    <children>
    <AnchorPane fx:id="contentBox" layoutX="1.0" layoutY="25.0" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="336.0" prefWidth="503.0" style="-fx-background-color: aqua;" />
        <MenuBar fx:id="menuBar" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="504.0">
         <menus>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Stock">
               <items>
                  <MenuItem fx:id="returned" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#showReturnedForm" text="Returned" />
               </items>
            </Menu>
         </menus>
      </MenuBar>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Now here is ReturnsInputPresenter

```
public class ReturnsInputPresenter implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    Button saveButton;
    @FXML 
    TextField orderNo;
    @Inject
    MainPresenter main;

    private ObjectProperty<FormOpener> newFormProperty ;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        this.newFormProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty();
        this.newFormProperty.addListener(new ChangeListener<FormOpener>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends FormOpener> observable, FormOpener oldValue, FormOpener newValue) {
                if(newValue!=null){                    
                    main.newFormProperty().set(newValue);
                }
            }
        }); 
    }

    public void save() {
        FormOpener fOpener = new FormOpener();
        fOpener.setInwards(false);
        this.newFormProperty.set(fOpener); 
    }

    public ObjectProperty<FormOpener> newFormProperty(){
        return newFormProperty;
    }
```

Here in `returnsinput.fxml` i have a text box and a button. On button's action i am setting the `newFormProperty()` to new Value which have a listener that changes the value of `newFormProperty()` belongs to `mainPresenter` and here when i try to access `contentPane`then it gives me a NPE while with menu Action performing the same process have no issue.
Why it's happening and what is the solution. Please help me with this.
               Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure the NPE coming from "contentBox.getChildren().add(inputView.getView());" line? and contentBox is null.

Comment: Yes @UlukBiy i am getting NPE at mentioned line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instance of `MainPresenter` that is injected into `ReturnsInputPresenter` is not the same instance as the one created for you when `MainView` is instantiated. (Imagine you had two instances of `MainView`, which is perfectly plausible, and consequently two instances of `MainPresenter`. How would the framework know which instance it should inject into the `ReturnsInputPresenter` instance?)

The problem here is really that you are trying to use the framework in a way that it is not intended to be used. Afterburnerfx is a framework for implementing MVP and the injection mechanism is really designed as a convenience for injecting elements of the *model* so that model instances can be shared by multiple presenters. It is not designed to pass around references to the presenters from one presenter to another.

But actually all you are trying to do is something that fits very naturally into MVP: you are trying to share a piece of data (specifically, an `ObjectProperty<FormOpener>`) among different presenters. So just define a class to hold that data (and other data you might need to share):

```
public class FormOpenerModel /* you can probably think of a better name */ {

    private final ObjectProperty<FormOpener> formOpener = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    public ObjectProperty<FormOpener> formOpenerProperty() {
        return formOpener ;
    }

    public final FormOpener getFormOpener() {
        return formOpenerProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setFormOpener(FormOpener formOpener) {
        formOpenerProperty().set(formOpener);
    }

    // other properties as needed...
}
```

Now your `MainPresenter` should look something like

```
public class MainPresenter implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    AnchorPane contentBox;

    @Inject
    private FormOpenerModel formOpenerModel ;

    // you probably don't need any of these references any more:
    ReturnsInputView returnsView ;
    ReturnsInputPresenter returnsPresenter;
    InwardsInputView inputView;
    InwardsInputPresenter inwardsPresenter;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        this.returnsView = new ReturnsInputView();
        this.returnsPresenter = (ReturnsInputPresenter) returnsView.getPresenter(); 
        this.contentBox.getChildren().add(returnsView.getView());
        formOpenerModel.formOpenerProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<FormOpener>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends FormOpener> observable, FormOpener oldValue, FormOpener newValue) {
                if(newValue!=null){
                    InwardsInputView inputView = new InwardsInputView();
                    inwardsPresenter = (InwardsInputPresenter) inputView.getPresenter();
                    contentBox.getChildren().add(inputView.getView());
                } 
            }
        }); 
    }

    public void showIncomingForm(){
        this.returnsView = new ReturnsInputView();
        this.returnsPresenter = (ReturnsInputPresenter) returnsView.getPresenter(); 
        contentBox.getChildren().add(returnsView.getView());
    }

}
```

You probably don't need all those references to the other views and presenters, etc, but I left them in. You should remove them if you don't need them.

Your `ReturnsInputPresenter`:

```
public class ReturnsInputPresenter implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    Button saveButton;
    @FXML 
    TextField orderNo;

    @Inject
    private FormOpenerModel formOpenerModel;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    }

    public void save() {
        FormOpener fOpener = new FormOpener();
        fOpener.setInwards(false);
        formOpenerModel.formOpenerProperty().set(fOpener); 
    }

}
```

(By the way, FXML controller classes haven't needed to implement `Initializable` since version 2.0, so you can get rid of `implements Initializable`, and if the `initialize(...)` method is a no-op as above, you can just remove it entirely.)

The injector is smart enough to cache instances when it injects them and reuse them (i.e. it uses the equivalent of "singleton scope" from CDI or Spring), so both presenters will get a reference to the same `FormOpenerModel` instance.

Comment: Thank you, Thank you, Thank you @James_D, Thanks a lot. It's working.

Comment: Hey @JamesD , i have a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32945485/org-eclipse-persistence-exceptions-conversionexception), sorry for the way i am mentioning you, hope you will help me, thank you